# RDLC - Default parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I m working on RDLC Report created by some one else before.
It has a report parameter defined  in it.

Now requirement is From Code behind no one is going to pass any values to Report Paramter, And i want value should be taken from one of the column of dataset by default.

When i right click Reportparameter there is an option called   DefaultValues - >get Values from a Query - >(Select Dataset and Value Field). After this when i run application , what i have is, Only empty screen.

Please let me know if anyone have any queries.

Comment: Do you mean you want to populate dynamically the parameter checkboxlist/dropdownlist based on, for example, the user profile ?

Comment: no i just want Defaault value of parameter should be the value of firstrow firstcolumn(or any column) in dataset.